# Python Requests doesn't get the correct page with the parameter specified

Tags: python

I've just tried doing this pythonchallenge.com [challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php) and I am using requests to open up the next site that is on the page.

```
import requests
import re


next_nothing = '12345'
for _ in range(400):
    req = requests.get(f'http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing={next_nothing}')
    html = str(req.content)
    next_nothing = re.findall('([0-9]+)', html)
    print(html)
```

It works on the **first**  two runs only but afterwards it skips to 72758 and just keeps printing '72758' even though it should be accessing the next page already.  Why doesn't requests work here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.findall` return a list, so you need to extract the first element:

```
next_nothing = re.findall('([0-9]+)', html)[0]
```

Alternative, I think it can be simplified:

```
next_nothing = req.text.split()[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

After the line:

```
next_nothing = re.findall('([0-9]+)', html)
```

Try printing the type:

```
print(type(next_nothing))
```

(Or even just the value: `print(next_nothing)`)

From there, it should be straightforward to fix.